# Using exec, how do you change the PHP version you're exec'ing with?

Tags: php

**initial-script.php**

```
exec("start /B php file.php >> log-file.log");
```

**file.php**

```
<?php die(phpversion()); ?>
```

**log-file.log**

```
5.5.11
```

I have 3 php installations in Program Files (x86):

- v5.4
- v5.5
- v5.5.5

I'm looking to force the exec to use v5.4, is this possible?

I've tried different variations to the **c:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.4/php.exe** file to no avail, usually the script just hangs.  One final note, I'm on a Windows 2008 server so 
nix commands are futile... :/

Comment: what about creating php.exe copies with different names, and adding them to PATH?

Comment: simply `exec("path/to/php/version/php file.php >> log-file.log");`

Comment: does this require the full path like so? `c:/program files (x86)/PHP/v5.4/php`

Comment: full error logging on? error logs? not easy to diagnose from here :(

Comment: Figured it out! In Windows, you can't have spaces in the path, they need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dagon pointed out, the path needs to be defined.  However, in Windows, you need to enclose paths with spaces using double quotes.  I was also not able to run the script with start /B as originally posted.  I'm also using popen now.  Here is the working code:

```
pclose(popen('"C:\/Program Files (x86)\/PHP\/v5.4\/php" file.php var1 var2 >> log-file.log 2>&1 &', "r"));
```

You'll also see that I've escaped the slashes, hence the `\/`.

Thanks for your help, SO.